# Rails undefined method nil:NilClass error on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Currently a user signs up and creates a profile. Once signed in they can create a project. On the project show page they have an option to add additional images with descriptions using this link:

<%= link_to "New Image", new_project_image_path(current_user.profile_name, @project) %>

The links works and it brings up images/new.html.erb but when I click create I get the error:

```
undefined method `images' for nil:NilClass
```

The line highlighted is in the create method -

```
@image = @project.images.new(image_params)
```

My user.rb file contains the following:

```
has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
```

project.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
```

image.rb

```
belongs_to :project
```

routes.rb

```
  scope ":profile_name" do
    resources :projects do
      resources :images
    end
  end
```

projects_controller.rb (I haven't finished this completely but it works to create the projects correctly)

```
before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    @projects = Project.all.order('created_at desc')
end

def new
    @project = current_user.projects.build
end

def create
    @project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
        flash[:success] = "Your project has been created."
        redirect_to project_path(@project.user.profile_name, @project)
    else
        flash[:alert] = "Sorry, your project could not be created."
        render :new
    end
end

def edit

end

def show
end

  def update
    if @project.update(project_params)
      flash[:success] = "Project updated."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Update failed.  Please check the form."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Your project has been deleted."
    redirect_to root_path
end

private

def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :attachment, :description, :slug, :user_id)
end

def set_project
  @project = Project.friendly.find(params[:id])
end

end
```

images_controller.rb (Not fully finished either as I need to sort out the re-directs when saved)

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController

 before_action :set_project



  # GET /images
  # GET /images.json
  def index
    @images = Image.all
  end

  # GET /images/1
  # GET /images/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /images/new
  def new
    @image = Image.new
  end

  # GET /images/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /images
  # POST /images.json
  def create
    @image = @project.images.new(image_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.save
        format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: 'Image was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @image }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end



  # PATCH/PUT /images/1
  # PATCH/PUT /images/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.update(image_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: 'Image was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @image }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /images/1
  # DELETE /images/1.json
  def destroy
    @image.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to images_url, notice: 'Image was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.


    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def image_params
      params.require(:image).permit(:user_id, :project_id, :title, :description, :link)
    end


    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

def set_project
  @project = Project.friendly.find(params[:id])
end

end
```

I can't work out what is causing it to end up as nil:NilClass. Any ideas?

If you need any further information please just let me know as I wasn't really sure what to include.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `before_action` callback in `images_controller.rb` to the following:

```
def set_project
  @project = Project.friendly.find(params[:project_id])
end
```